# Explanation for “à + infinitive” in this context?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, infinitif

What is the grammatical rule for à + infinitive in sentences like:

> On a passé notre jour au parc à jouer et à bavarder.
>
> Je suis à l’hôtel à manger mon dîner.

Comment: I think the explanation lies in the fact that the verb ( jouer) follows a preposition ( à)

Answer (score 2):

1. > On a passé notre jour**née** au parc à jouer et à bavarder.

Here ***à*** is used as a preposition to an infinitive.

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0):

> **I.−** À dans le syntagme verbal (à sert à construire un complément du verbe)
>   ...
>   **B.−** À introduit le complément indirect dans une double construction
>   ...
>   **4.** À + inf. (ou subst. d'action), compl. de destination
>   ...
>   **c)** Le compl. dir. est de l'inanimé; il n'est ni « suj »., ni obj. de l'inf. :
>   *ils mettent leur élégance **à** ne pas se montrer il mit pareille patience **à** parfaire ...il ne mettait donc aucune bonne volonté **à** fournir ... elle mettait tout son orgueil **à** faire reconnaître ... il mit tous ses efforts **à** me maintenir ... ils mettaient bien du temps à pousser ... il mit quelques instants **à** comprendre il mit plus de vingt ans **à** retrouver ... il mit une semaine **à** mourir consacrer du temps **à** faire qqc. dépenser son existence **à** faire fortune dépenser une partie de son argent **à** décorer ... employer cette demi-heure **à** visiter ... utiliser ses connaissances **à** faire ... attacher le plus grand prix **à** démontrer ...*

---

2. > *Je suis à l’hôtel, à manger mon dîner.*

This form can be used but is literary. Here ***à*** has a durative meaning:

> *I'm at the hotel, having dinner.*

It has also often a depreciative connotation. The hotel guest is probably not having fun.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as the "to + infinitive" in English.

It works well in your second example:

"I'm at the hotel to eat my dinner".

It's a bit flaky in the first example because you would not say it this way in English, but you can still use "to + infinitive" like so:

"We spent our day at the park to play and [to] talk."

(The meaning is changed slightly when using "to + infinitive" in this case. It should, of course, be translated as "[...] at the park playing and talking." in order to keep the same meaning.)

Comment: English is not the topic but I somewhat disagree, I speculate the second sentence is _while_ + continuous and not about the "purpose" for being at the hotel. Further I'm of the opinion the use of _à_ slightly differs in the two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

> On a passé notre jour au parc à jouer et à bavarder.

In this first case the pattern is « verbe - COD - infinitif », and it is a possible one for certain verbs only.

The [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) makes precise that this is a pattern in which

"*Le complément  direct  est de l'inanimé; il n'est ni « sujet », ni objet de l'infinitif.*".

Here are a few examples from the TLFi; they are current;

il mit quelques instants à comprendre
il mit plus de vingt ans à retrouver ...
il mit une semaine à mourir
consacrer du temps à faire qqc.
dépenser son existence à faire fortune
dépenser une partie de son argent à décorer ...
employer cette demi-heure à visiter ...
utiliser ses connaissances à faire ...

> <s>Je suis à l’hôtel à manger mon dîner.</s>

That form is not used; You should say this;

- Je suis à l'hôtel **en train de** manger mon diner.

Comment: Et moi je suis sur mon smartphone, à commenter ta réponse...